# Extract images from PDF file with jspdf or other npm package

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jspdf

Good day.
Is there any way to extract image from pdf file using jspdf library or other npm libraries.
Maybe there are some solutions for react?

I will be grateful for help.

Comment: Unfortunately this function is needed in the project

Can you give examples of such functions? I'll be very grateful

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 4):

I got all images from pdf file using 'pdf-lib' and 'stream-mime-type' libraries.
Here is the function itself, I hope it will be useful.

```
const {PDFDocument} = require('pdf-lib');
const fs = require('fs')
const {getMimeType} = require('stream-mime-type')
const createJpgFile = require('./utils/createJpgFile.js')
const path = require("path");

async function getImageFromPdf() {
  const existingPdfBytes = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fs.readFile(path.join(rootPath, 'test.pdf'), (err, result) => {
      if (err) {
        reject(err)
      }
      if (!err) {
        resolve(result)
     }
   })
  })
  const pdfDoc = await PDFDocument.load(existingPdfBytes)
  const pages = pdfDoc.getPages()
   const result = []
  pages[0].doc.context.indirectObjects.forEach(el => {
     if (el.hasOwnProperty('contents')) result.push(el.contents)
   })
  const mime = await Promise.all(result.map(async (el) => {
     return new Promise(async (resolve) => {
       const res = await getMimeType(el)
       if (res) {
         resolve(res)
       }
     })
   }));
   await Promise.all(mime.map(async (el, i) => {
       if (el.mime === 'image/jpeg') {
         return new Promise(async (resolve) => {
           const res = await writeJpgFile(result[i], `image-${i}`, 
 'jpg')
          resolve(res)
         })
       }
     })
   )
 }
```

add:
I also wrote a function that parses jpg images from a pdf file without using third-party libraries. The function finds the beginning of jpg images by signature. For other formats, you need to use other signatures.

```
const parserJpegFromPdf = async () => {
  const existingPdfBytes = await getArrayBufferFromPdf()
  const convertedBuffer = new Uint8Array(existingPdfBytes)
  const firstBeginSignatureSymbol = parseInt('ff', 16)
  const secondBeginSignatureSymbol = parseInt('d8', 16)
  const indexesStartSignatureImage = []
  convertedBuffer.forEach((el, i) => {
    if (el === firstBeginSignatureSymbol &&
      convertedBuffer[i + 1] === secondBeginSignatureSymbol &&
      convertedBuffer[i + 2] === firstBeginSignatureSymbol &&
      (convertedBuffer[i + 3] === parseInt('e0', 16) ||
      convertedBuffer[i + 3] === parseInt('e1', 16) ||
      convertedBuffer[i + 3] === parseInt('e2', 16) ||
      convertedBuffer[i + 3] === parseInt('e3', 16) ||
      convertedBuffer[i + 3] === parseInt('e8', 16))) {
        indexesStartSignatureImage.push(i)
    }
  })
  const resultSlicedCodeImage = indexesStartSignatureImage.reduce((arr, 
el) => {
    arr.push(convertedBuffer.slice(el));
    return arr
  }, [])
  await Promise.all(resultSlicedCodeImage.map(async (el, i) => {
    await createFile(el, `test_image_${i}`, 'jpeg')
  }))
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone else stumbles upon this and doesn't want to implement the various cases of conversion (grayscale, with/without alpha etc.) him/herself, I finally found a library that does everything for me - [pdf-img-convert](https://github.com/ol-th/pdf-img-convert.js). It uses pdf.js under the hood.

```
npm install pdf-img-convert
```

And use like this:

```
import { convert } from "pdf-img-convert";

const outputImages = await convert("/path/to/pdf.pdf");
const imagePaths = outputImages.map((image, i) => {
  const path = "output" + i + ".png";
  writeFileSync(path, image);
  return path;
});
```